# Meaning of 感じる in sexual context

Tags: meaning, words, verbs, colloquial-language, manga

Context: a character of a manga is being interviewed in the extra section at the end of the manga. She receives a question about a chapter in which she had sex with another character after talking to him.

> 第１７話のあの時ですが…　ぶっちゃけ感じてました？

I know that `ぶっちゃける` means `to speak frankly`, but what is the meaning of ぶっちゃけ感じてました? Are they asking her if she felt that the boy was sincere/honest? Or is it a question about her own sincerity? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 感じる is used in having sex, it means "to feel sexual stimulation", "to feel good (sexually)".

So it means "Frankly, were you feeling good?".

Comment: I see, I had to separate ぶっちゃけ and 感じる. I'll change the question title then. Thank you for your answer!