# Don't know how should I understand the meaning of this sentence correctly, since there are too many meanings for 感じすぎる and しっかり

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**感じすぎるとは言っても、しっかりと腰振りは続けられている。**

**I'm reading an eroge, and there are too many meanings for "感じすぎる/kanjisugiru" and "しっかり/ shikkari" , so I'm not sure how should i understand this sentence.**

**Hope someone can help me to understand its correct meaning. (i can only guess : "Even though she said she feel too much, she still continues at it steadily " ?)**

Context: A h-scene between MC and his maid.

> チンポ全体を柔らかな膣肉で擦りながら、身体から膣内まで痺れるように震えている。 膣からは新たに熱い蜜液が滲みだしていた。

> Maid「ご奉仕に集中しないといけないのに、主様のおチンポが気持ちよくて、感じすぎてしまいますぅ♥　うっくぅ……♥」

**感じすぎるとは言っても、しっかりと腰振りは続けられている。**

それはメイドとしての意地か、はたまた快感と欲望からか。あるいはその両方かもしれない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know (if any) an idiomatic English expression, but 感じる in such contexts means *to feel pleasure in the sexual sense* as noted in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53790/45489).

しっかり is just normal *steadily, firmly*. Here, it is assumed that the feeling good makes the girl sort of passive or stop moving voluntarily. The sentence says *although she is getting the pleasure, she still continues to 'serve' MC (by moving herself* - again I don't know how to express the movement 腰を振る).